# How to use go modules on nested git packages?

Tags: golang

I am trying to use pulsar from golang and i am trying to migrate my project from dep to go modules since some of the newer libraries prefer go modules.

When i tried to create a new project and run

```
dep ensure -add github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go/pulsar@v2.4.1
```

**it works perfect**,I am getting 2.4.1 tag it loads the correct cgo library everything is great.

But in go modules when i try to do like

go.mod File:

```
module sample 
go 1.13 
require (   github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go/pulsar v2.4.1 )
```

It fails with

> require github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go/pulsar: version
>   "v2.4.1" invalid: unknown revision pulsar-client-go/pulsar/v2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

`dep` uses *import paths*. Modules use *module paths*, which are slightly different. To find the module path, you need to track down the `go.mod` file and [look at the module name](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-client-go/go.mod#L1).

The module you're trying to use is `github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go`, without the `/pulsar` suffix. There is no `go.mod` file at `.../pulsar-client-go/pulsar/`.

Once you have the proper module path in your `go.mod` file, you may then use the import path in your code.

```
package foo

import "github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go/pulsar"

func Foo() {
    pulsar.Foo()
}
```